# Graphic - Type text on picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

Is there a way to type/edit text on a `PictureBox` or `Panel`? When user click somewhere on the `PictureBox`, the caret is shown and allow user to type text. I am making a program about graphic. I want it like text tool in MS Paint or Photoshop. But I have no idea. Someone has experience about this please give me a guide.

Comment: @GrantWinney please check the question again, I have just edited it. Don't worry about font color/size. I think I can handle it when the text is added. My problem is type text on a picturebox just like in a textbox. We can select, move the caret ...

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code that you maybe can work on to get it to work for you:

```
private void image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float y = (float)Cursor.Position.Y -50;
        float x = (float)Cursor.Position.X -50;

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Dozer789\Downloads\notepad-png.bmp");

        RectangleF r = new RectangleF(x, y, 0, 0);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawString("yourText", new Font("Thaoma", 8), Brushes.Black, r);

        g.Flush();

        image.Image = b;
    }
```

You will have to edit and add some stuff but it is at least a start.

Hope this works!!

Comment: This is to draw text in code. I have already known this. But what I need is on the interface, user can interact. Click on somewhere and then type somethings. Like the way you add some texts in MS Paint. It has a caret, you can move the caret or select text as well.

Comment: g.DrawString("yourText", new Font("Thaoma", 8), Brushes.Black, r); the "yourText" is unknown at compile time. That is the problem.

Comment: We are not here to make code for you, we are here to help you, you didn't even post any code and you want me to make the whole code for you. What i would suggest is to start typing out the lines just by yourself and that will give you experience and it will remove the errors.

Comment: Oh, I know your code is working. It seems you didn't get my idea. I don't know how to do so I make this topic to find a start point. Your code is to draw text at the mouse click position. I known that already. But it can be done if we had the text. In my case, user will type text on their own. Type on the picture box. They click on and the caret appear. And then they start to type what they want.